# Automatically update Windows 8 hosts file when creating subdomains with WordPress multisite

Tags: windows, xampp, hosts, wordpress

So I have set up WordPress Multisite locally to test etc. I have set it up so new sites are on subdomains. When I create a new subdomain I will have to manually create a new entry in the hosts file. Is there any way to do this automatically when the new subdomain is created?

Also, when I put this site live, will I be able to get the server to do this automatically? Similar to how when you create a new subdomain on WordPress.com? I'm sure they don't have a team of people manually updating the DNS records everytime someone creates a new WordPress blog.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way I know of to easily automate the hosts file in Windows for subdomain wordpress-mu install emulation short of writing your own batch program. What yo can do is use a 3rd-party DNS proxy program like [Acrylic](http://mayakron.altervista.org/wikibase/show.php?id=AcrylicHome) and set it up to use wildcard subdomains. For example if your main install is at somesite.com the wildcard DNS entry would be *.somesite.com.

On a live production server this is how it works and you'd have to also add a wildcard subdomain for it to automate. Depending on your setup it can be done through your hosting control panel or if you are using a 3rd-party DNS provider then you add that asterisk as an A entry in the DNS record pointing to the IP address of your deployment. WordPress MU will do the rest automatically for you.